# Const has no effect when passing class member by reference in c++

Tags: c++, constants

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class ObjectCalculator {
public:
    struct Object {
        int id = 0;
    };
    void setObject(Object& object) const {
        object.id = 1;
    }
    Object m_object;
};

int main() {
    ObjectCalculator objCalc{};
    std::cout << objCalc.m_object.id << std::endl;
    objCalc.setObject(objCalc.m_object);
    std::cout << objCalc.m_object.id << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I thought this this line should throw an error during compilation since the internal variable is changed via `const` method `setObject`:

```cpp
objCalc.setObject(objCalc.m_object);
```

but the code compiles with no errors and outputs:

```cpp
0
1
```

Could you please clarify why `const` does not have effect in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter itself be given the qualifier?

Comment: `void setObject(Object& object) const` --> `void setObject(const Object& object) const`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` related to the members of the class.
You modifying the method argument, so it can be changed, regardless of `const`.

`const` after method applied to the implicit first method argument `this`, through which all class members accessed.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-_and_volatile-qualified_member_functions)

> A non-static member function can be declared with a `const`, `volatile`,
>   or `const volatile` qualifier (this qualifier appears after the
>   parameter list in the function declaration). Differently cv-qualified
>   functions have different types and so may overload each other.
>
> In the body of a cv-qualified function, the `this` pointer is
>   cv-qualified, e.g. in a `const` member function, only other `const` member
>   functions may be called normally. (A non-const member function may
>   still be called if `const_cast` is applied or through an access path
>   that does not involve this.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One thing I wanted to clarify though, when I call `objCalc.setObject(objCalc.m_object)` the `objCalc.m_object` is passed by reference, so technically its address does not change, i.e. the compiler should see this as a class member and prohibit the change? Why isn't it happening?

Comment: `const` method:
`void Object::setObject(const Object* this, Object& object)`.`this` is implicit for all non-static class methods in C++. non-const method:
`void Object::setObject(Object* this, Object& object)`.
Access to the class member inside method is `this->m_object`, it's going through `this` pointer and `const` matters at this moment, inside method.
Compiler theoretically can see, that you passes reference to the class member, but it can't do anything with it and it should not. It's just `Object&`. Compiler knows nothing about addresses, it operates with AST(Abstract Syntax Tree).

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier is to tell that the function does not modify `this` object.

By passing the object to modify as an argument you don't modify `this`, you modify the object passed as an argument.

If you tried to modify `m_object` in the function, you would get the error you expected.